# Android: set alarm on button click

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarm

I have a text field where I type the alarm that I want to set in the following format: `DAY/MONTH/YEAR`, e.g. 01/08/2020. When I click the button, I need to set the alarm to this date. How do I achieve that?

```
set_alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        add_alarm();
    }
});

public void add_alarm(){
    //how to set alarm on this date?
    final String AlarmDate = item_expire_date.getText().toString();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

```java
final String AlarmDate = item_expire_date.getText().toString();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(AlarmDate, formatter);
```

The variable date now has parsed `Localdate` type object which is understood by java.time package

[Refer java.time package summary for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

That being said, I suggest using a datepicker type element instead of a  plain textfield for date picking, as this can lead to exceptions when users don't type out **exactly** as you would like them to.

Comment: @Cenfrancee where do you use the ```AlarmDate``` string?

Comment: Nice, and how do i set alarm to the ```LocalDate date``` object?

Comment: I presume you're referring to Android development? [Refer AlarmManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)